# What are the main Differences between KJV and Duoay-Rheims (DRB) / douay-rheims vs kjv / Differences between KJV and DRB Douay-Rheims Version (DRV)

Tags: hebrew-bible, bible-versions

Douay-Rheims Bible: I will put enmities between thee and the woman, and thy seed and her seed: she shall crush thy head, and thou shalt lie in wait for her heel.

This is correct, since evil cheat the Eve and Eve needs to punish the devil. And the New Eve is Mother Mary.

King James Bible: I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.

Its mentioned like "It" God cannot be mentioned like "it" and some other bible they change to "He" and "It". Its not correct

Conclusion: Douay-Rheims Bible - one original bible translated from first latin vulgate bible.

Comment: ה֚וּא is indeed 3rd person singular masculine [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/3-15.htm) but I wouldn't throw away the KJV for a minor fault. I can show you far more grievous faults in the Douay Rheims.

Answer (score 1):

The DRB is based on the Latin text. In other words, it is a translation of a translation. The KJV is based on Greek texts in the N.T, (none of which were earlier to the tenth century), and the Masoretic text in the O.T.

Comment: Correct - the DRB is not based on the original Greek text but a translation of the Greek text into Latin.  Further, the Latin text use is the Clementine Text (1592) as distinct from (say) the Jerome Latin text of about 400 AD.  The Clementine text show frequent departures and additions compared to the Greek text.

Comment: @Dottard The Challoner translation is from Jerome's Vulgate, I believe.

Comment: That cannot be true as I have discovered numerous places where DRB agrees with the Clementine text but NOT Jerome.

Comment: @Dottard I am only quoting from the preface of my copy of the D-R.

Comment: OK, that is interesting.  It is not hard to tell - does it have 1 John 5:7b & 8?  If so, that is NOT in Jerome but is included in the Clementine text.  My copy of the DRB, Challoner is the Latin text approved by Pope Pius XII which would not be Jerome - only the Clementine text was produced and approved (in anticipation) by the Council of Trent.